# Adding contextmenu for QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt, qt4

### Inside constructor

```
connect(ui.UserSpecificMaterial_treeWidget, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)),this, SLOT(ContMenu(const QPoint &)));
```

### Inside slot

```
void MyContMenu::ContMenu(const QPoint &pos)
{
 QTreeWidgetItem *item = ui.UserSpecificMaterial_treeWidget->itemAt(pos);
     if (!item)
         return;
    QMenu *menu = new QMenu(ui.UserSpecificMaterial_treeWidget);
        myAction = menu->addAction("Remove");
    myAction->setIcon(QIcon(QString::fromUtf8("Resources/Remove.png")));
    myAction->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+D"));
    myAction->setStatusTip(tr("Remove the respective material from the User DB"));
    menu->exec(ui.UserSpecificMaterial_treeWidget->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
          /---code to remove the item ./ }
```

In the above code whenever i right click on the QTreeWidgetItem  it will show me the contextmenu having a single menuitem named Remove  . What i want is whenever the user click on that remove menuitem at that time only it should remove that QTreeWidgetItem from the qtreewidget . but in the above code after rigtclick even if i click on any part of the UI it removes the respective QTreeWidgetItem from the treewidget , which i want to avoid .

Thankss in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check the return value from QMenu::exec(...).

Like this:

```
QAction* item = myMenu.exec(QCursor::pos());
```

Now you can check against for instance the QAction::text() method to see if Remove was actually clicked or not.

Comment: Hey thanks brother . .Here i found that my QMenu::exec itself is not working .Can you please say what might be the reason ?

Comment: QAction* item1 =  myMenu.exec(QCursor::pos());

Here exec returns a null pointer . so in the next line when i am trying to execute QAction::text() my application got crashed .

Comment: This means no Action was chosen. So after the line I quoted, you first have to check if item equals zero. If so, do nothing. Else, you can call QAction::text() and check for the 'Remove' label.